# Refresh a polymer element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to detect attribute change, then to refresh the element.

I do

main.dart

```dart
library main;

import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";
import "dart:html";

void main() {
  initPolymer().run(() {
     Polymer.onReady.then((e) {
       querySelector("nav-bar").setAttribute("mode", "ok");
     });
   });
}
```

navbar.html

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="nav-bar" attributes="mode">
  <template if="{{mode == null}}">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </template>
    <template if="{{mode == 'ok'}}">
    <p>Youpie</p>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="navbar.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

navbar.dart

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('nav-bar')
class NavBar extends PolymerElement {
  @published String mode;

  NavBar.created() : super.created();
}
```

When I put my element in index.html, whatever "mode" value, I have always `Hello`.

When I change the mode using query, nothing happen. The text should be changed...

I did something wrong ?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?! There are better ways to get notified on attribute changes.

Comment: What is the better way ? And how I can reload the element ?

Comment: The word `reload` is a bit weird in relation to Polymer elements. You have to ensure Polymer gets `notified` about model changes and it then makes sure the model changes are reflected in the DOM but usually nothing gets reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that should solve the problem

```dart
querySelector("nav-bar").mode = "ok");
```

or

```dart
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true) String mode;
```

or both (in my opinion it would be best to apply both)

Comment: Does not work too. The most strange, it's if I put directly my tag with the attribute (`<nav-bar mode="ok"></nav-bar>`), the result is not as expected.

Comment: You could try to add `{{mode}}` somewhere outside your `<template if="{{mode}}">` to see what value is used. Have you tried your example from the comment above with or without my suggested change (`@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)`).

Comment: I tried both. I added {{mode}} (`<template if="{{mode == null}}">
    <p>Hello {{mode}}</p>
  </template>`). The result is `Hello ok` ... It should be "Youpie". I had tried to inverse the conditions. And whatever the condition, it's always the first template who is displayed.

Comment: Can you make your project (or better a minimal example to reproduce) avaialable on GitHub so I can try. This is a very basic Polymer function and is used successfully in many places. It's probably a minor oversight.